# Inno Setup RegKeyExists on 64 bit systems

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I created a setup with Inno Setup and wanted to query the registry using Pascal Script

```
 if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Classes\\Installer\UpgradeCodes\342603A924F08FA4B95B5C283FC13D13') then
```

My setup is 32bit (as is my Software I want to install), but on 64bit systems, the query is redirected to `HKCR\Wow6432Node\\Installer\UpgradeCodes`

Of course, the key is not found, even though it is there. How can I detect the key even though my setup remains 32bit?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I figured it out. You can make a helper function like this in your script:

```pascal
function GetHKLM: Integer;
begin
  if IsWin64 then
    Result := HKLM64
  else
    Result := HKLM32;
end;
```

Then you use it like e.g.:

```pascal
RegQueryStringValue(
  GetHKLM, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment', 'XYZ', Variable);
```

Comment: How do you declare **Key**? What type is it? I just get a type mismatch error.

Comment: The RegKeyExists function checks for a Key, not a value. Browse regedit for the path, use an existing upgrade code and see if the function returns true.

Comment: Does anybody know how you declare the variable "Key" used in the above code sample? I asked last year but no reply :(

Comment: I updated my post. I did not understand what you meant last year :-/. Key was just a local variable inside a function. The Result variable in my updated example is predefined and represents the return value.

Comment: You don't have to 'declare' any key, "HKLM64" and "HKLM32" are internal variable (tested with succes on Windows 10) :)