# Not able to query value from registry inside HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE using RegQueryStringValue

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to retrieve the installation directory of a game, I've already found it in the registry, so I tried using this code

```
if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App XXXXX','InstallLocation', Dirpath) then
    ;rest of the code;
```

But it'll always return false, even if there is such value.

I've tried with another value inside HKLM and it returns false too, so the problem seems that I'm not able to query values from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

After identying my real problem (not being able to access HKLM) I was able to found a answer in StackOverflow [Inno Setup RegKeyExists on 64 bit systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429554/inno-setup-regkeyexists-on-64-bit-systems)

Sorry for not doing all my homework before posting